# Once one person replies, the post is ignored from then on out, even if the question isn't resolved

Tags: discussion

I've posted a lot, and when one or two people respond, that's the end, no one wants to post anymore.  I don't know the rules here, but it's like people are just "firsting" to get points or something.  Once they post, even when they can't help, the post is ignored and no one else will help.
My questions aren't getting answered because people who don't really know what they're talking about, or don't care to REALLY help me are posting.  I've tried to include in my posts to not "first" on my posts and only answer if you're willing to help, but the moderator removed that part.
What's up??? I'm not getting the help I need because of this.  Really aggravating.

Comment: Maybe it due to the unclarity of the question

Answer (score 9):

It was removed because it was not adding any context to the question. The site isn't necessarily an end to end help desk, people supply their knowledge to get you on the right track.

Sometimes that is with a specific example, like solutions to faulty code. Sometimes it is a higher level answer that you have to draw your own conclusions from to get you on track, as every SharePoint environment is different or the question is a higher level concept.

People are here on their own free time, answering people's questions for free, there should be no expectation of support. While some people see the question all the way through, others don't for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Thanks Eric.  So you do all this for free?

Comment: Yes, we are not paid for this, we do it in our off time to help others as best we can.

Comment: You personally have always been helpful, it just seems like there are too many cooks in the kitchen, and no one really knows how to cook.  There's no way to regulate what people are posting, even if they're wrong.  I can't rate people's answers, because I don't have enough gold coins or whatever because I've never answered anyone's question (I recognize that I can't cook), and once someone posts, that's it.  I don't get any other responses.  I would pay money for assistance (and have) if I could get some legitimate help, but it doesn't seem to exist.  So, this is what I've found and I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm not trying to be ungrateful, but this system just doesn't make sense for people actually trying to learn SharePoint.  Maybe it's not set up to be learned???  Thanks.

Comment: @Lauren I'm not sure what you are getting at. But this place is truly for sharing problems and sharing solutions to problems (if one knows how to resolve the problem). All is done pro-bono by the members of the community, no one is getting payed to answer questions. The best you can do is to try to write as precise and informative questions as possible so that people are able to answer them at ease. That improves the chances of your question being answered. Also, googling the basics around a problem often helps you in gaining enough information to write a well written question

Comment: I'm not getting at anything.  I'm trying to be clear.  It's a really frustrating and unhelpful set up that once someone initially answers your question, it's like it just dies, and if that person's answer doesn't help, you either have to repost the question (which I've done), or give up.  I just think that, if this site is really to help people, I should be able to say "no, that wasn't it" and see what someone else has to say.

Comment: I appreciate the attempts, but people have suggestions on how their system works, but they don't have full scope and once they answer with what works for them, they can't help after that, and no one else picks up the question.

Comment: Just like this one.

Comment: At some point the conversation has to end. If you are interested in learning, there are other sources out there. This isn't necessarily the avenue for a step by step, how do I complete this task type of site, and I've been busy hauling waterlogged junk out of my dad's basement the past 2 days. If you can't handle the transient nature, this might not be the best place for help.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. I've tried Harbar.net, LearnNowOnline, W3schools, MSVirtualAcademy, ChrisStahl, ShareGate, Credera, SharePointShepherd, Dynamics101, Lynda, a number of other no-name SP "experts," Youtube, CriticalPath classroom training, and forget Microsoft or Office online (set up for 365). I've looked into training locally with NewHorizons, Accelebrate, and LearningTree, but it's not in the company budget. I've even tried to find evening classes, that I would pay for personally, without luck.

Comment: It's not yours or anyone else's job to ensure that I learn what I need, and while I appreciate your help, quite frankly, I really don't see why you or anyone else would care about some name on the screen. But after all of my research, it seems like SharePoint is set up to stay confusing, and when I follow people's advice on the Internet, who pretend like they know what they're doing, it injures me more than helps (I've had entire company content wiped out because of a script I found online). I have to do my job- my family needs to eat, and I don't know what to do. Sorry about your dad's house.

Comment: I had little knowledge starting out, I had to discover a lot of it for myself through trial and error and usage, I really jacked up content types for several sites very badly. There is so much to know,  I've been doing SP for about 8 years and there are a lot of things I don't know. You might want to look into the certification test prep courses if you want deep, technical information. Every farm is different, from hardware to configuration.

Comment: Thank you Eric.  I'll look into that.  Thanks for your help.